# Why can't I call subscript on SKScene?

Tags: swift, swift3, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sknode

Apple documentation says that `subscript(_:)` is a method of SKNode.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode/1483070-subscript

The documentation also says that SKNode inherits from SKEffectNode, which inherits from SKNode. My beginner's understanding of this says that SKScene should have all the same methods available to it that an instance of SKNode would have.

However, in my GameScene subclass of SKScene, code hinting does not reveal the subscript method. If I try to use the method as follows, I get an error.

```
self.subscript("sensor")
```

Can anyone explain why this method seems to be unavailable? None of my research online has turned up any explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subscript` is not a method of `SKNode`. (Note that the documentation you linked does not say `func subscript`.)

`SKNode` has a subscript *operator*.

```
let sensorNodes: [SKNode] = self["sensor"]
```

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm still getting used to reading Apple's documentation. Also new to programming in general and I guess I haven't covered operators yet. So the example you provided is the correct way to use the subscript operator?

Comment: It is the correct way in the case of `SKNode` (or `SKScene`).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I noticed in the Overview section of the SKNode documentation (under "Searching the Node Tree") that it refers to subscript as a method: "The subscript(_:) method returns an array of nodes that match a particular name." But I guess that must be a typo.

Comment: In case you want to learn more, subscripts in Swift are documented [in the Swift Programming Language (Swift 3.1) book](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Subscripts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH16-ID305).